# Scroll bottom div on top of the div placed above

Tags: html, css

I have tow divs in a flex container, one containing the chart and another containing it's legends as below :

[image: Initial State of the Div]

When I scroll on the div below, it should scroll up on the chart like so :
[image]

Here's my attempt at this with z-index and position absolute :

HTML -

```
      <div className={`${style['chart__doughnut-wrapper-opportunity']} ${props.class}`}>
        <div className={style.chart__data}>
          <div className={style.chart__doughnut}>
              <Chart
                className="chart"
                data={tabChartData}
                width={props.width}
                height={props.height}
                options={optionsForGraphic(
                  props.type,
                  props.orientation,
                  tabChartData,
                )}
              />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={style.chart__legend}>
          <div className={style.chart__table}>
              <ChartLegend
                chartType={'doughnut'}
                page={props.page}
                legendData={tabChartData}
                percentage={percentage}
                legendColor={legendColor}
                legendStyle={legendStyle}
              />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS :

```
  .chart__doughnut-wrapper-opportunity {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
max-height: 13.5rem;
margin: 1.25rem 0rem;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: #dadbdf solid 0.063rem;
.chart__data {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 13.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
  .chart__doughnut {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    canvas {
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}
.chart__legend {
  display: flex;
//  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20rem;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
  z-index:10;
  .chart__table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 20rem;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

}

Which has resulted in something like this :

[image]

I am stuck, not getting any ideas, please help.

Comment: Is your main goal to align then vertically or in a column?

Comment: Forgive me for being naive, but don't vertically or in a column mean the same ? When I scroll in the legend div, it should scroll up eventually covering the graph.

Comment: Yeah that's the same. I just want to make sure I understanding it right? You mean the legend should be scrollable both of them?

Comment: Only the legend div should be scrollable, the graph div is fixed on top,

Comment: I see, I'll look into it. You just want css or any solution is fine?

Comment: If I could Get a CSS only solution/advice It would be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244067/discussion-between-crystal-and-nazir).

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the overflow to the chart_legend class and let's see

Comment: add overflow-y: "scroll" on the div you want to be scrollable, you can remove the scrollbar if you want yourSelectorOfTHeDIv::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}, for chrome